# Lock regional AWS IoT core to a specific CA

Tags: ssl-certificate, aws-iot, ca

I am working with custom CA (certificate authority) on AWS IoT. I wonder if there is a way to lock it down to only my CA? i.e. only allow connections from devices that present my custom CA certificate (and not AWS IoT build in certs) upon connection initiation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generate the certificates with a particular attribute then a condition in the policy can be used. This condition could restrict connections to those with a particular attribute in the certificate.

e.g.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Action":[
        "iot:Connect"
      ],
      "Resource":[
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:123456789012:client/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
      ],
      "Condition":{
        "ForAllValues:StringEquals":{
          "iot:Certificate.Subject.Organization.List":[
            "Example Corp",
            "AnyCompany"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The list of certificate policy variables is at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/cert-policy-variables.html